# Is it possible to build a lens system that allows you to capture an orthographic projection of the real world?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

I am a bit of a computer graphics geek and I find it fascinating how difficult it is to wrap ones mind around what an orthographic projection looks like as the world rotates.

I know nothing about the theory here but was curious if in real life it was possible to view an orthographic projection of the real world. Obviously you would probably need to have a fixed viewing angle and position and perhaps a lens as big as the area you wanted to see but is it possible to craft a lens that allows one or a camera sensor to see the world without perspective projection?

Obviously as close to perfect as possible would be better than an approximation but if there is a way to do an approximation I would be interested in knowing it.

Comment: Are you asking how to design a lens for perhaps a satellite which can photo a hemisphere?  Must the original image be orthographic or will you allow postprocessing to add or remove distortion?

Comment: Original image would be coolest i guess. Although I imagine it might be hard to avoid distortion past the center. And that’s a great point about satellites. I guess they are so far away that it almost looks like that kind of projection?

Comment: Note: because you can only see things directly in front of the lens (not off to the side) you need an extremely large lens. For example, to take a picture of a person you would need a lens at least the size of a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, you may achieve a very-near orthographic projection image with a special type of lens called telecentric lens (more accurately, you need to use an "object-space telecentric lens").

In optics, telecentricity means that the aperture of the optical system is projected to infinity. If it's projected to infinity at the object's side, we say that the lens is "object-space telecentric", and that would a achieve an orthographic projection of the object at the image side. The aperture may also be projected to infinity at the image side (where a sensor, film or observer eye usually is) and then we say that the lens is "image-space telecentric", but that does not cause the imaged object to appear orthographically projected. The lens may also be telecentric at both side, making it a fully-telecentric or bi-telecentric lens.

Projecting the aperture of the optics to infinity essentially means that the angle of view is close to 0° (or all chief-rays are close to parallel to the optical axis of the lens), which eliminates perspective errors.